# Java array to input student names according to their number

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an array that prompts a professor to input how many students are in their class. Then prompts them to input their names until the number of students is met. What I have is clearly wrong but I was hoping for some insight.

```
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of students in the class: ");
    int numberOfStudents = console.nextInt();


    String [] studentName = new String [numberOfStudents]; 

    for (int i=0; i<studentName.length; i++)
    {

    System.out.println("Enter the name of student " + (i+1) + " in your class. ");
    studentName[i] = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Student name entered: " + studentName[i]);
    }
```

EDIT: I changed the code a bit, mainly the array. With the for loop I am intending to simply have it go through each number and assign a student name to it. But with the last line of code it gives me an error saying its a confusing indentation.

EDIT 2: After proofreading my question and the code myself I've noticed very basic mistakes and have dealt with them, but one last question. Right now while the code works, when it asks for me to input the name, it skips student 1, leaves it blank then moves onto student 2. As shown in this screenshot http://puu.sh/8fl8e.png

Comment: What exactly is your question? You should be specific here. If you just want input on your code you may want to try [CodeReview](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: shouldn't the type for studentName be `String` instead of `double`?

Comment: Sorry all, going to edit the code and question to make a little more sense!

Answer (score 1):

you weren't far...

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of students in the class: ");
    int numberOfStudents = console.nextInt();


    String [] studentName = new String [numberOfStudents];

    for (int i=0; i<studentName.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the name of student" + (i+1) + "in your class. ");
        studentName[i] = console.next();
    }
```

to test the code:

```
    for (int i=0; i<studentName.length; i++){
        System.out.println(studentName[i]);
    }
```

**EDIT**: an answer for your second edit:
use

```
console.next();
```

instead of

```
console.nextLine();
```

Comment: Yep! After my own proofreading I realized the very basic mistakes I made, it all works fine now save for one thing. The code does not allow me to input for the first student. As shown in this screenshot http://puu.sh/8fl8e.png

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `studentName` should be String, not double. And maybe you should consider taking advantage of fact that Java is OO? :)

Comment: Mmhmm, it was a large mistake to upload this question without proof reading, the edit should ask what I am trying to fix as of now.

Answer (score 0):

since you are taking names as input which is string type but you are using double(not possible to store string) and you also missed bracket after for loop.
change

```
double [] studentName = new double [numberOfStudents];
```

to

```
String [] studentName = new String [numberOfStudents];
```

final correct code:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of students in the class: ");

int numberOfStudents = console.nextInt();

String [] studentName = new String[numberOfStudents];

for (int i=0; i< numberOfStudents; i++){

    System.out.println("Enter the name of student" + (i+1) + "in your class. ");
    studentName[i] = console.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of students in the class: ");
int numberOfStudents = console.nextInt();


String [] studentName = new String [numberOfStudents]; 

for (int i=0; i<studentName.length; i++)
{

System.out.println("Enter the name of student " + (i+1) + " in your class. ");
studentName[i] = console.nextLine();
System.out.println("Student name entered: " + studentName[i]);
}
```